# Passing parameters to Jenkinsfile job triggered by schedule

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkinsfile job accepts some parameters used inside the groovy script. Such job is triggered by SCM polling and cron with multiple schedules. I'd like to set different  values for job parameters depending on the schedule's times. Is it possible? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct method, you can write a groovy library for this and use that method to define parameters based on the scheduled times.

Comment: I'd assume the same, but add a `sh "printenv"` and check, if there's a difference in the available environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the plugin [Parameterized Scheduler Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Scheduler+Plugin).

It lets you define many cron-like formatted entries, but with additional parameters for each definition.

Usage examples:

```
#run against the integration at 15 past the hour
15 * * * * % env=int
#run against the QA at 30 past the hour
30 * * * % env=qa
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18549133)

Comment: Yeah. I've just improved my answer a little bit. Check it out. Sounds better? :)

Comment: Much better. Thanks.